# Can't figure the issue with these simple lines of code for Linear Regression

Tags: python, linear-regression

I have some issues with Linear Regression, I just used a simple sample and I still get error, don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code:

```
x = [1,1,2,3,1,1,2,0,4,1]

x = np.array(x)

x = np.reshape(1,-1)

y = [1.24,0.88,0.88,1.31,1.36,0.79,0.79,0.79,1.36,1.36]

y = np.array(y)

y = np.reshape(1,-1)

lin_reg = LinearRegression()

lin_reg.fit(x,y)


"ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."
```

Comment: Reshape `y`? `y.reshape(-1, 1)`

Comment: You should examine what this returns: `np.reshape(1,-1)` and ask yourself if that's the value you really want. You need to call `reshape()` on the actual arrays.

Comment: @yatu should it be `x.reshape(-1, 1)` ? Features need to be a 2D array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says what you should do in this case.

Just use `.reshape(-1, 1)` instead of `.reshape(1,-1)`.

Do it only for `x` and the problem is solved.

```
x = [1,1,2,3,1,1,2,0,4,1]

x = np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1) # Edited line

y = [1.24,0.88,0.88,1.31,1.36,0.79,0.79,0.79,1.36,1.36]

lin_reg = LinearRegression()

lin_reg.fit(x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, would you mind a simple explanation why there’s no need to reshape y?

Comment: Of course. If you check [official documentation of sklearn concerning linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) you can see this `y array-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_targets)`. In other words, you don't need to reshape your `y` since it's already agreeding the required shape to train model with `fit`.

Comment: Please be kind and mark my answer if it solves your problem. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

you called the `reshape` function wrong.

If you want to reshape the `x` or `y` matrices, you should call like:

```
x = x.reshape(1, -1)
```

or combining with one line before:

```
x = np.array(x).reshape(1, -1)
```

If you only call `np.reshape()`, nothing would happen to your data.